# Implementing an interface I and extending a class B that implements interface J parent of I

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles, command-pattern

I have an interface for an entity of a game `IEntity` such that

```java
public interface IEntity {
    getATK();
    setATK();
    getDEF();
    setDEF();
}
```

So I can call game items commands constructors such as `atkPotion(IEntity entity)` without depending on any implementation (at least that's why I learned from SOLID DIP). However, I also have two common types of entities (with exclusive attributes), just like

```java
public interface IPlayer extends IEntity {
    setEXP();
    getEXP();
}
    
public interface IMonster extends IEntity {
    setElement();
    getElement();
}
```

that are also interfaces in order to use `expPotion(IPlayer)`, `elementDungeon(IMonster)` commands and not broke DIP.

The problem comes out when I want to make an implementation `StdPlayer` of `IPlayer` and another `StdMonster` of `IMonster`, but both approaches have the same behaviour for `getATK()`, `setATK()`, `getDEF()`, `setDEF()`. It is correct to make a general implementation `StdEntity` such that `StdPlayer` extends `StdEntity` and implements `IPlayer`, and `StdMonster` extends `StdEntity` and implements `IMonster`? Or there is a way better approach for this problem?

Comment: How about `ILivingEntity`? It can share the commonalities of monsters and players without over-specifying `IEntity`. Also there is no requirement for a concrete `StdEntity`

Comment: What you are suggesting is OK.  But note that this approach only works with a single base class ... because Java allows a class to only extend one other class.   (Alternatives *might* include default methods in interfaces ... depending on the nature of the common methods.)

Comment: My advice: try it and see!  OO programming is best learned by *doing* it,

Comment: This is the problem with SOLID. Instead of designing models that fit their application requirements, developers now design models that satisfy the SOLID principles.